# How can i create a pulse-like settings view? See photo

Tags: android, android-view, pulse

As topic. Does any one know how to create that snap-settings-view the pulse app uses to its left?

I.e. When you swipe your finger from the left edge, the settings start to show from behind. See the left part of the image below. After a certain amount of movement, the settings menu snaps almost all the way to the right, but still shows the underlying view.

[image: pulse app settings view]

Any help is much appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- you can either do yourself with two fragments (one in front and one behind) and some touch even listener translating the drawer to open and close.
- or use a library that is probably doing the same thing I've described. Something like this one: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/sliding-menu/

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I can't believe how people find such sites as androidvi***.net =)